# Live Monitor IIS 6 taffic/# of connections

Tags: iis

Does anyone know of any tools that will allow you to monitor all traffic for every website in IIS 6 in real time or close to real time? Have a way of getting the number of current connections to IIS would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Perfmon (performance monitor) has several [IIS-specific counters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737281(WS.10).aspx).